# Seeing weight of a code from generator matrix

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Let $\Bbb F_4=\{0,1,w,w^2\}$. I have a code $C \subset \Bbb F_4^6$ where $C=\{(a,b,c,a+b+c,aw^2+bw+c, aw+bw^2+c )|a,b,c \in \Bbb F_4\}$

I found the generator matrix of C:  $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&w^2&w\\0&1&0&1&w&w^2\\0&0&1&1&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I was able to prove that C is a linear $[6,3]$-code using the generator matrix and a theorem for the properties of a linear code.

I also found that $C$ has minimum distance $4$ by using the fact that it is MDS, since any $k=3$ columns are linearly independent, and thus the minimum distance has to be $n-k+1=6-3+1=4$. Since $d(C)=W(C)$, for a linear code, then the minimum weight of $C$ is also $4$.

Now I have to prove that there are no words of weight $5$ in C. This appears pretty clear to me, since every row in the generator matrix only has weight $4$ and adding rows by multiples still equals a row of weight $4$.

However, is there a way to fully prove this without having to write out the $k^q=3^4=81$ different codewords in $C$?
Thank you very much for your help!

I was thinking of using the lemma $w(x-y)=d(x,y)=w(x)+w(y)-2w(x \cap y)$. Since $x-y$ is in $C$ because it is closed under addition, then by the lemma the weight of $x-y$ has to be even, and thus cannot be $5$? But I think this lemma only applied to $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: $(a,b,c,aw^2+bw+c, aw+bw^2+c )$ are 5 components... shouldn't they be 6?

Comment: Thank you! Edited!

Comment: Yes. That lemma applies only to the alphabet $\Bbb{F}_2$. But, there are only $4^3=64$ codewords, so it's not so bad :-). Because (non-trivial) scalar multiples have the same weight, you actually get away with just 21 checks! If you already checked linear independence of $\binom 63 =20$ sets of three columns then it should be ok :-) Hmm....